# Foreign key vs. SET data type MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, set

I have a MySQL database set up with a list of all my movies, which I imported from a MS Access database. One field contains the possible values for the genre of the movie, movies can have more than one genre, so I need a data type which supports this feature. In access I could link one table 'genre' to the field 'genre' in my table 'movies', so I could choose none, one ore multiple genres per movie. When I switched to MySQL I used the SET data type to define all the possible values. So far everything is running perfectly.
I am now trying to set up a table in html/php to show the mysql table. I want the table to be able to sort on: title, genre, quality, rating, etc. But for the sorting on genre, I would need the possible values from the set data type. I don't know if it is possible to get the values with some php command/code, but after I lurked around on the web for a while, I didn't see many applications where they use the SET data type for obvious negative reasons.

So I started looking into the Foreign Key possibility. The problem I have here is that -for as far as I know- the key can only contain one possible value, which puts me right back at the start of my problem. I do like the idea of a foreign key, because it would make it way easier for me to add a new genre to the list.

Is there a possibility I am overlooking? Is it possible to either get the values from the SET type to php or to use a foreign key with multiple possibilities for one record?

I know I can also put every genre in my php script manually, but I'd like to have it all on one place. So that if I add a movie with a genre I haven't defined yet, I can just update it at one place and everything else adapts to it.

Comment: i would have another table `film_id,genre_id` with as many rows per film as needed

Answer (score 0):

Dagon is absolutely right here - you have an issue with the structure of the tables in your back end. You are wanting to model a many to many relationship when at the moment with your current back end the best you can do is a one to many relationship.

To review:
You have individual films that can have many genres
And you have individual genres that are related to many films

Relational databases actually don't model many to many relationships with one relationship they use recursion of the one to many relationship and create two joins.

To model a many to many relationship you need three tables
A film table (which I think you already have)
A genre table (which I think you already have)
A junction table which as Dagon suggests will consist of two fields film id and genre id.

You then set up two separate one to many relationships. One from the film table to the junction table and one from the genre table to the junction table.

Now if you want to know all the genres a film is in you simply filter the junction table on the relevant film id and if you want to know all the films with a certain genre you filter the junction table on the genre id.

Set up lookups to relate your genre ids to textual descriptions and bang you are free to change the textual description as much as you want and the great thing if you've done it right it will upgrade every single value in your forms.

This is an absolute fundamental concept of the algebra of sets behind the design of SQL and relational database design.